# how to filter an input so that it only contains the value (no date), python

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, filter

I have some code :

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({ 'sentencess' : sentencess, 'publishedAts' : publishedAts, 'hasil_sentimens' : hasil_sentimens })
df.to_csv('chart.csv')
df['publishedAts'] = pd.to_datetime(df['publishedAts'], errors='coerce')

by_day_sentiment = df.groupby([pd.Grouper(key='publishedAts',freq='D'),'hasil_sentimens']).size().unstack('hasil_sentimens')

sentiment_dict = by_day_sentiment.to_dict('dict')

sentiment_dict_new = {k: {m.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'): v if v == v else 0 for m, v in v.items()} for k, v in sentiment_dict.items()}

print(sentiment_dict_new)
```

and the output from sentiment_dic_now is :

```
{'Negatif ': {'2019-08-28 00:00:00': 2.0, '2019-08-29 00:00:00': 3.0}, 'Netral ': {'2019-08-28 00:00:00': 1.0, '2019-08-29 00:00:00': 5.0}, 'Positif ': {'2019-08-28 00:00:00': 0, '2019-08-29 00:00:00': 1.0}}
```

How to filter it so that it only contains the value (no date)??
Like this one

```
Negatif : [2,3]
Netral : [1,5]
Positif : [0,1]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
x = {'Negatif ': {'2019-08-28 00:00:00': 2.0, '2019-08-29 00:00:00': 3.0}, 'Netral ': {'2019-08-28 00:00:00': 1.0, '2019-08-29 00:00:00': 5.0}, 'Positif ': {'2019-08-28 00:00:00': 0, '2019-08-29 00:00:00': 1.0}}
{k:list(v.values()) for k, v in x.items()}
```